# Amazon AWS reserve instance expire

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am very new don’t have any experience in amazon AWS Linux. I have 3 instance in Amazon AWS, which reservation period expire & now I am paying per hour’s rate basic. I saw there is an options that we can by new reserve instance.

But all the configuration are in running instance & all are production server.
I have few queries? Please let me known. Thanks all in advance for valuable suggestion.

Is there any way that I can convert expire instance to reserve instance again?
If no what are the others options to reduce monthly cost?

Answer (score 4):

As soon as you purchase a reserved instance, as long as it is the same type and region and availability zone as an on-demand instance you already have, the reserved instance will automatically apply to the existing on-demand instance.  You do not need to get a "new" instance.  (This is similar to how your expired reserved instances turned into on-demand instances.  The instances themselves did not change.)

From https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/:

> When you purchase Reserved Instances, you select a configuration to
>   match your On-Demand instances that have the highest utilization. The
>   billing discount is automatically applied to any running instances
>   that match that configuration. You can also purchase Reserved
>   Instances to apply to On-Demand instances that you intend to purchase
>   in the future. As long as the reservation and instance specifications
>   match, the discount will be applied.